# ResponsiveSlides: slideshow ignoring Pause when click the nav buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I use [ResponsiveSlides](http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/) to create slideshow. I've notice a bug when I enable the auto slide (`auto: true`), the nav (`nav: true`) and the pause on hover (`pause: true`).

I get this issue: when I move mouse on the navigation buttons (next or prev, placed on the slideshow) the slideshow stops and it's ok because of pause:true, but when I click the button the slideshow start to slide all the slides (and not only one).

Do you have this issue?

Comment: Rename the plugin "UnresponsiveSlides" then at least it will be appropriately named :-)

Comment: The issue is not related to the responsive thing... for that it works very well. Maybe you can suggest me a better one?